# Порекомендуйте пакет Ribbon для Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Хочу разнообразить внешний вид своих прог. А переходить на новые версии Delphi не хочется. Естественно, что можно было и не задавать вопрос, а самому порыться в Инете. Однако, может уже кто-то работал? Есть ли стабильный пакет?

Answer (score 1):

Я предпочитаю работать с **AlphaControls**, бесплатно для СНГ, хороший форум, стабильные версии.

[Вот линк](http://www.alphaskins.com/index_rus.php) на оффсайт для жителей СНГ

Comment: Вячеслав Кириченко: СПАСИБО.

Answer (score 0):

Есть широкоизвестные [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExBars/ribbon.xml) и [TMS](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advtoolbar.asp).

DevExpress выглядит более похожим на настоящий. Кроме того, родной дельфийский Ribbon очень сырой(Delphi 2010), невольно приходится пользоваться сторонними инструментами.

Comment: Вячеслав Кириченко: СПАСИБО. Но не хочется искать пирата.

Comment: **TMS** делает хорошие вещи но цена :( к сожалению не доступная.

Comment: да ну бросьте... TMS Component Pack из 300+ компонентов это €195 за  одного дева или €695 за всю компанию. Не так и много, если речь идет о коммерческой разработке.

Comment: Вот делфи закупить, особенно если с Enterprise плюшками, да дороговато.

Comment: Ну на самую простую версию DelphiXE я насобирал, а вот от **TMS** решил отказаться.